# cannot make file in web server codenvy

Tags: php, webserver, codenvy

I just make a web server in codenvy.
I make a php file that fwrite to make .txt file
After I run that php, there isn't .txt file created in codenvy project.

But if I fscanf after fprintf in 1 php file, it print the content of .txt file that I  just fwrite.

What  I should I do for make .txt file in codenvy project?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are not able to create permanent files when you run application. When you run application you always get new test environment and this environment disappears just after stop of your application. Run feature != hosting but chance to try your application before deploy it somewhere.